# 1:n relationship is m:n with SqlTypeProvider in F#?

Tags: f#, type-providers

I have really simple database:

[image]

- Room is located in House.
- The House could have multiple Rooms.
- Every Room is **just in one house**

With F# SQL type provider it appears, that one Room has multiple Houses :

```
let oneRoom = db.Rooms |> Seq.head
let addressOfHouse = (oneRoom.``dbo.Houses by id`` |> Seq.head ).Address
```

Why `|> Seq.head` is necessary for reaching Address of House from one Room?

**Sql Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE [Houses] (
  [id] int IDENTITY (1, 1) ,
  [Address] nvarchar(255), 
 PRIMARY KEY ([id])
) 
GO

CREATE TABLE [Rooms] (
  [id] int IDENTITY (1, 1) ,
  [Description] nvarchar(255),
  [id_Houses] int, 
 PRIMARY KEY ([id])
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [Rooms] ADD FOREIGN KEY (id_Houses) REFERENCES [Houses] ([id]);

INSERT INTO Houses VALUES ('Our house, in the middle of the street');
INSERT INTO Houses VALUES ('What a place for us to meet');

INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES ('Bedroom', 1);
INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES ('Bathroom', 1);
INSERT INTO Rooms VALUES ('Kitchen', 2);
```

The schema was generated by http://sqlcompact.dk/sqldesigner/

Comment: Would you be able to paste in the SQL schema for these 2 tables, that could help

Comment: I've got a dummy version of this setup locally and am getting the exact same issue, I thought it may be because `[id_Houses]` was nullable, but changing the schema that didn't help

Comment: Databases and ORMs tend to return a sequence for many things even if it contains one item. Think about it this way, what would be the type of a function that consumes this input `someFunc (x:'T)` or `someFunc (x:seq<'T>)`, the latter case will be able to handle all three possibilities: zero (empty sequence), one (just as you got it above), many rooms (possible with a different query). It's possible that individuals in the sqltypeprovider always returns a sequence.

Comment: I've just tried this schema in Linqpad (which I believe uses Linq-SQL to provide the types) and it doesn't have this issue I can do `Rooms.First().Id_HousesEntity.Address` (C#).

Comment: Yes. This is exactly the weird thing. With C# and EF everything works fine. So I blame type providers...